# how to find glibc version with C preprocessor?

Tags: c-preprocessor, glibc

glibc since 2.19 requires `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` be defined to get `stdlib.h` to define `putenv()`.  Before that it needed `_SVID_SOURCE` .

Is there any way for code to magically detect which version of glibc it has, and thus define the correct `_SOURCE` symbol, or even that glibc is present?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check the glibc version using the `__GLIBC__` and `__GLIBC_MINOR__` macros. (Eg., in version 2.29, `__GLIBC__` is 2 and `__GLIBC_MINOR__` is 29.) Every glibc header sets these macros, so you can test them after the first `#include`. Unfortunately, that is too late for this particular use case, because you need to `#define` feature-test macros *before* any system header is included.

Fortunately, for the particular issue raised in your question there is no need to check the glibc version.

`putenv` is an XSI (X/Open System Interfaces) extension in Posix, and you can request XSI extensions by placing `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` before the first system header include. That will work on all glibc versions, and on most other standard library implementations. So it's much simpler and more portable than idiosyncratic glibc-only feature-test macros.