# How to disallow compilation against older shared libraries in cmake

Tags: c, cmake, version, libc

I have a cmake C project that needs to be compiled against libc.

I want to use a function (`getgrouplist`) that contains a bug in glibc versions prior to 2.3.3.

I want to disallow compilation on machines that have glibc 2.3.3 or older, but I don't want to link to a specific version.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You may write a small source file, which checks `__GLIBC__` and `__GLIBC_MINOR__ ` macros (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59597130/3440745) and emits `#error` in case the version is too small. Then you could use [try_compile](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_compile.html) command for check, whether given file can be successfully compiled for the target environment.